# unión de varias tablas access y carga en una existente

Tags: sql, ms-access

Estoy atascado con el access en esta consulta.

Necesito que a partir de varias uniones me meta los datos en una tabla existente (que tiene la misma estructura que el resto):

```
SELECT * insert into historico from tabla1
union
select * from tabla2
union
select * from tabla3
UNION select * from tabla 4
ORDER BY fecha;
```

El tema es que me da error el access, dice algo de "error reservado -3087"

Comment: varias cosas: 1.- error en https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/01acbbd6-d61b-4f27-adf3-b4669d87b796/reserved-error-3087?forum=officeitproprevious. 2.- tienes el orden mal, primero insert y luego selects. de hecho empiezas, select * insert, cuando espera un from

Comment: Hola iria he metido el insert into delante del select y al consultar la tabla me muestra resultados pero ahora me dice si ejecuto la consulta que una de las tablas de origen o destino tiene un campo multivalor y que no puedo usar select...sabes como podría resolverlo? el formato de los campos no puedo tocarlos

Comment: prueba a leer la documentación sobre SQL, aunque ya tengas la Query hecha te valdrá para el futuro

Answer (score 1):

La sentencia correcta es muy distinta de la que muestras. Primero debemos poner el `insert` y luego el `select`, pero además no nos podemos valer del `*` y debemos poner la lista de campos, esto es un requisito del `union`.

```
insert into historico (fecha, campo1, campo2, campon)
SELECT fecha, campo1, campo2, campon
from tabla1
UNION ALL
SELECT fecha, campo1, campo2, campon
from tabla2
UNION ALL
SELECT fecha, campo1, campo2, campon
from tabla3
UNION ALL
SELECT fecha, campo1, campo2, campon
from tabla 4
ORDER BY fecha;
```

Comment: ok, pero me sigue dando el error del campo multivalor y no la ejecuta en el access